# How to send search id to `$resource` prodiver?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

when user lick on an element, I am changing the search params. after updating my search params, my url location changing to like this :

`http://localhost:3000/#/projectSummary/1?id=3`

now how to i send my `$routeParams` like this?`http://localhost:3000/#/projectSummary/1/3`

here is my try :

```
    $scope.conractorInfo = function ( contractor ) {

                $location.search('id', contractor.Id); //setting id

                console.log($routeParams.id) //getting `1` not 1/3 !?

server.contractor.get({id:$routeParams.id+'/'+contractor.Id}).$promise.then(function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                });

            }
```

Here is my server.js

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("tcpApp")
        .factory("server", ['$resource', function ($resource) {

            var base = 'http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/';

            console.log(base + 'GetProjectDetails')

            return {

                splash : $resource( base + 'GetProjectDetails'),

                summary : $resource( base  + 'GetProjectByID/:id'),

                contractor : $resource( base + 'projects/:id/:id')

            }

        }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure $resource for 2 different params.

Right now you are using the same param twice in the url so there is no way to parse object keys into 2 different ones

It should be more like:

```
// factory
contractor : $resource( base + 'projects/:id/:contid')

// controller
server.contractor.get({id:$routeParams.id, contid:contractor.Id})
```

Comment: It works. can't i required to set the `contid` from `$routeParams` - just object id is enough?

Comment: not sure what that means but so long as you have it working ..things are good I guess